# Restrict items does not return any results, just 0

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I prepared the tool, which is downloading email attachments based on user restrictions. Its working well, but when I was implementing it into new person from other dep I had a weird problem, becouse restrict functionality is not working at all. I provide the mailbox, the folder and with restrict details as below and it returns 0, when I checking each email thru loop its see all of them.

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olMailboxFolder = olNamespace.Folders("FolderA").Folders("FolderB")

strRestriction = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(myStartDate, "DDDDD HH:MM") & "' AND [ReceivedTime] < '" & Format(myEndDate, "DDDDD" & " 23:59") & "'"

Set olEmailFound = olMailboxFolder.Items.Restrict(strRestriction)
```

It could be something with outlook/folders setup? If code would be wrong it wont work anywhere, but its only one person...

Comment: What is or When is `myStartDate`? & `myEndDate`? assuming its date, which date is?

Answer (score 0):

You must use proper formatting of the date value string expressions:

**Not working:**

```
strRestriction = "[ReceivedTime] >= #" & Format(myStartDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn") & "# AND [ReceivedTime] < #" & Format(DateAdd("d", 1, myEndDate), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

**Working:**

Doc reference: [Items.Restrict method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict)

> Although dates and times are typically stored with a Date format, the
>   Find and Restrict methods require that the date and time be converted
>   to a string representation. To make sure that the date is formatted as
>   Microsoft Outlook expects, use the Format function.

However, the documentation is buggy. The `AM/PM` part misses the slash:

```
sFilter = "[LastModificationTime] > '" & Format("1/15/99 3:30pm", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
```

What seems to work in an International environment, is the predefined formats. Thus, this works with a Danish localisation:

```
Dim StartDate    As String
Dim EndDate      As String
Dim n            As Integer

StartDate = Format(myStartDate, "Short Date") & " " & Format(myStartDate, "Short Time")
EndDate = Format(myEndDate, "Short Date") & " " & Format(myEndDate, "Short Time")
strRestriction = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & StartDate & "' And [ReceivedTime] < '" & EndDate & "'"

Debug.Print strRestriction
Debug.Print olMailboxfolder.Items.Count

Set olEmailFound = olMailboxfolder.Items.Restrict(strRestriction)
For n = 1 To olEmailFound.Count
    Debug.Print n, olEmailFound.Item(n).ReceivedTime
Next
```

Note, that if seconds is included in the formatted strings, the comparison will fail.

Comment: unfortunately with your solution is not working at all, even there where it was working. I think that could be related to date format. Each email has following format of receive time "08/05/2019 10:58:46". It works when I change into:

[code] strRestriction = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(myStartDate, "dd\/mm\/yyyy hh\:nn") & "' AND [ReceivedTime] < '" & Format(DateAdd("d", 1, myEndDate), "dd\/mm\/yyyy") & "'"

Comment: Can't tell. It is tested and works here and our default format is also dd-mm-yyyy. `[Received]` does hold a true date value, thus if passing a string, as you do, this will be casted out of your control to a Datetime value before the comparison is made.

Comment: It's really weird. I was checking your solution with the person, which has a problem and olEmailFound.count gives still 0. For example email receivedtime is 12/06/2019 11:26, restriction is set into 12/06/2019 00:00 till 13/06/2019 00:00 and the result is 0. At my computer it gives 1 :D What I can check more?

Comment: Uh, I didn't check carefully enough, and how about studying the documentation? See edited answer, please.

Comment: Gustav, I have preprared code based on documentation and yours answer. I made a modification with EndDate string to: EndDate = Format(DateAdd("d", 1, myEndDate), "Short Date") & " " & Format(myEndDate, "Short Time") to have a one day timerange.

strRestriction string give me as below for time range 08.05 - 08.05: 
[ReceivedTime] >= '08/05/2019 00:00' And [ReceivedTime] < '09/05/2019 00:00' 

olMailboxFolder.Items.Count give correct number of items in folder, thats mean that I'm in right place.

But olEmailFound.Count give me still 0, it could be related to date setting for Win?

Comment: My last attempt would be to check with the (corrected) _Format_ string from the documentation: `"ddddd h:nn AM/PM"`.